# Express.js App on Phusion Passenger - did not write a startup response in time

Tags: node.js, express, passenger, phusion

I am trying to run an express.js app on a server running Phusion Paggenger (apache) and am seeing the error "An error occurred while starting the web application: it did not write a startup response in time." after the request times out. I've read through https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems but this seems a bit obscure. My express app is as bare-bones as possible so I'm wondering if anyone knows if there may be a component specific to express that might cause this. I have been able to run a plain node.js app with the same setup on the server.

Answer (score 9):

If you used the `express-generator` command to set up your project, you might see if pointing your Virtual Host configuration file's `PassengerStartupFile` line to `bin/www` instead of `app.js` does the trick instead of explicitly calling `app.listen` in the `app.js` file. Phusion Passenger's [documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/nodejs/digital_ocean/apache/oss/wheezy/deploy_app.html#edit-apache-configuration-file) does not address this specific convention adopted by ExpressJS. You can read some about this `bin/www` startup convention on Express's [Moving to 4.x guide](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html#app-gen). Seemed to work for me.

Comment: I had a similar problem for standalone Passenger with an Express app made with the express-generator, and started the app successfully with `passenger start --startup-file bin/www`.

Comment: On my DreamHost shared server, this setting is in .htaccess. I just added `PassengerStartupFile bin/www` to `.htaccess` and restrted and that did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you need to explicitly call app.listen within app.js. Specifically, I do this only when in production:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    app.listen(3000);
}
```

at the end of app.js

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting here from google. This is now documented with Passenger: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/nodejs/reverse_port_binding.html

A working example of a simple express app is below:

```
if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) != 'undefined') {
    PhusionPassenger.configure({ autoInstall: false });
}

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var body = 'Hello World';
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length);
    res.end(body);
});

if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) != 'undefined') {
    app.listen('passenger');
} else {
    app.listen(3000);
}
```